# Is there a simpler way of performing and grouped sum ina matrix?

Tags: python, list, matrix, grouping

I'm trying to perform a groupby sum but without pandas or numpy.
Here's what I've done:

```
t = []
u = []

data = [[[1,11], [1, 10], [2, 20], [2,15], [2, 100], [3, 56]]]

for x in data[0]:
    t.append(x[0])
'    print(x[0])'

u = list(set(t))
'print(t)'
'print(u[1])'
t = [0]*(len(t)-1)
for i in range(len(u)):
    for x in data[0]:
        if x[0] == u[i]:
            t[i] = t[i] + x[1]
            'print(t[i])'

'print(t)'
t.remove(0)
'print(t)'
t1 = list(zip(u, t))

t1
```

The output is correct, however the code is damn ugly and in the original task I must groupby the matrix by two categories and not just one so the code would be uglier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import collections

data = [[[1,11], [1, 10], [2, 20], [2,15], [2, 100], [3, 56]]]
# why not data = [[1,11], [1, 10], [2, 20], [2,15], [2, 100], [3, 56]] ???

sums = collections.defaultdict(int)
for k, v in data[0]:  # data[0] because data is in strange format
    sums[k] += v
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i'm not sure if i allowed to import collections sadly :/

Comment: @LucasCarvalho You can do the same with a normal `dict`, just add line `sums.setdefault(k, 0)` before `sums[k] += v`

Comment: thanks @zvone 

do you have any idea if this approach works with a data with 3 dimensions? like:
    `data = [[['a',10, 22], ['a', 10, 23], ['b', 10, 24], ['b',15, 55], ['c', 15, 34], ['d', 56, 55]]]`

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a [default dict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = [[[1, 11], [1, 10], [2, 20], [2, 15], [2, 100], [3, 56]]]


def grouped_sum(matrix):
    groups = defaultdict(int)
    for y, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for x, (group, value) in enumerate(row):
            groups[group] += value
    return groups


print(grouped_sum(data))
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 21, 2: 135, 3: 56})

# or if you need it in with the same type
print(list(grouped_sum(data).items()))
# [(1, 21), (2, 135), (3, 56)]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i'm not sure if i allowed to import collections sadly :/

Comment: are you able to use a dictionary?